# Android SDK fails to install

Tags: android, sdk

When I try to install the android SDK it fails to install.

My OS is Windows XP
I just downloaded and installed Java JDK 1.6
Java -version from the command line returns:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
java version "1.6.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 14.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

My environment vars have:
JAVA_HOME=c:\progra~1\java\jdk1.6.0_11

I downloaded android-sdk-r04-windows.zip

I unziped it in V:\AndroidInstall\

When I go to the

V:\androindinstall\android-sdk-windows>
and type "SDK Install.exe"  nothing happens...
If I go this from graph

When I do this from a graphical file viewer I get a quick flash that looks like a command line window and nothing....

When I try to run 
android list targets

from the tool directory I get:

Error: Error parsing the sdk.
Error: V:\androindinstall\android-sdk-windows\platforms is missing.
Error: Unable to parse SDK content.

So the basic install setup is not happening.

Additional clues:

I have a G1 and Android 1.0 was running on this machine. (Almost a year ago)

I've updated my G1 to 1.6 so I thought I'd update my SDK before starting new development.

When I tried to upgrade it tried and then died as the "directory was in use" 
So I cleaned out all the android directories, rebooted and redownloaded everythign from scratch.
Now it won't run at all.

I've clearly got something in an unhappy state, but I've cleaned up all the directories and no remanants seem to be running I've rebooted....

I've missed somethign I just can't figure out what.

Paul

Comment: I think you are going too fast.  When I double-click on the SDK Install.exe file, I get that same "flash" that looks like a CMD window.  After about 5 seconds, the SDK Manager will then come up.

Comment: Nothing comes up even if I let it sit for minutes.

Answer (score 7):

You should manually create 2 more directories under your root sdk dir 'android-sdk-windows':

1. platforms
2. add-ons

and than start SDK Setup.exe from the root directory or try to open it from Eclipse 
'Window' -> 'Android SDK and AVD manager'

Comment: This fixed it for me running Windows8Pro from a clean install.  The problem is that eclipse was being run as a user and not admin so could not create these directories since they were located in the "Program Files" directory by default.  Also found I had issues installing packages from the SDK manager later so needed to just right mouse click on the 'adt-bundle-windows-??' folder and add 'Users' to have full permissions.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue as well. how lame of Google to release their an IDE with a non working Android SDK included under Windows.

Answer (score 2):

1. Run the SDK setup
2. Wait for the error message
3. Disable anti virus
4. Install this unlocker program http://download.cnet.com/Unlocker/3000-2248_4-10493998.html
5. Run the unlocker program
6. select the tools directory to unlock it
7. select yes in the installer.

This is what worked for me.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4410#c41

Answer (score 1):

The directories "platforms" and "add-ons" need to be manually installed in the android SDK directory (parallel to "tool"). This is only necessary in a new installation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, adding the directory add-ons got rid of the error when eclipse is first open but I still couldn't download packages from the sdk manager.

What solved this problem for me (in windows 8) is running eclipse as administrator.

Comment: Same for me.  Seems like it needs to create a `temp` dir in the installation folder, by default that's not allowed on Windows 7/8.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error from my Jenkins CI.

It was because the Jenkins user did not have permissions on the `android-sdk-linux` folder.

(not the best solution but fixed it with):

```
 sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/bin/android-sdk-linux
```