# Some SDK installation problems

Tags: android, sdk, installation

I would like to install the Android SDK with Eclipse.  To start, I downloaded the SDK, the .exe for Windows as I am running XP Pro.  It started and asked me to install the JDK.  I stopped the SDK and installed the JDK.  I was then able to install the Android SDK loading all the platforms.  I then installed Eclipse Helios for Java and, following the instructions for "Hello World", I added the ADT.  Continuing to follow the instructions, I started a new Java project.  Unfortunately, on the new project page, there were no build targets listed and I could not proceed.  To solve this I tried uninstalling the JDK, the JRE and the Android SDK and reinstalling them.  This time, after installing the JRE and the JDK, the SDK continues to report that the JDK is not present and will not proceed with it's install.  Any suggestions?

Comment: When you go to START->RUN->cmd<ENTER> type java -version.  What do you get returned?

Answer (score 0):

After install you need to restart, then open the Eclipse preferences and tell where is the SDK location on your hard disk.

I think this should you help.

Answer (score 0):

This similar post should help

[Android SDK installation doesn't find JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4382178/617750)

*Also See*
[Android SDK fails to install](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2010620/617750)
[Android SDK install problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4394584/617750)