# Setting JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, windows, command-line, environment-variables

I'm having a problem when running programs that use Java from the command line. I get back a message saying Java.exe could not be found.

[image]

I've followed the [instructions found in several places for setting JAVA_HOME in Windows 7](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONF26/Set+JAVA_HOME+variable+in+Windows).

[image]

As can be seen in the image I'm pointing to the JDK folder as instructed, I've also tried several variations including linking to the bin folder(where java.exe is located).

What am I doing wrong, and how can I debug this.

*EDIT:*

Typing Set in Command Prompt outputs

[image]

Comment: Did you restart your command console? environment variable changes don't take effect until the console has been closed and re-opened. Also you may need to add JAVA_HOME to your PATH environment variable. You can do this by editing the path and adding the entry `%JAVA_HOME%;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As many have mentioned I had to add...

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_version\bin
```

...to the path variable.

However what was not mentioned and was stopping this from working was that I had to make sure
java\bin directory is in the path statement before the windows\system32 directory, otherwise this will not work.

I was able to find the information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5734845/773263).

Answer (score 16):

If you **don't have admin rights**, use the below command to set environment variables for java using the **command prompt**

```
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0"
setx PATH "%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin";
```

**Modify** the environment variable.

```
setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0"
setx -m PATH "%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin";
```

Answer (score 8):

1. Set the **JAVA_HOME** Variable

   **Windows 7** – Right click My Computer and select Properties > Advanced

   **Windows 8** – Go to Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings

   **Windows 10** – Search for Environment Variables then select Edit the system environment variables

[image]

2. Click the **Environment Variables** button.
3. Under **System Variables**, click **New**.
4. In the **Variable Name** field, enter either:

   **JAVA_HOME** if you installed the JDK (Java Development Kit)

   or

   **JRE_HOME** if you installed the JRE (Java Runtime Environment). In the **Variable Value** field, enter your JDK or JRE installation path .

[image]

5. Open Command Prompt as **Administrator**.
6. Set the value of the **Environment variable** to your JDK (or JRE) installation path as follows:

   > setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\path_to_Java\jdk_version"

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that the jdk.xxxxx/jre/bin folder is in your PATH

Comment: Notice the part of my question where I say " I've also tried several variations including linking to the bin folder(where java.exe is located)." 

Have tried it from the bin and I still get the same behavior. Restarted the command prompt but not the computer.

Comment: JAVA_HOME and PATH are different, I didn't say point JAVA_HOME to the jre/bin directory.  Try making sure that the PATH environment variable includes the jre/bin directory.  For example, type java from the command prompt, does that work?

Comment: When I type Java in command prompt it seems to work, tells me the usage

Comment: Can you update your answer with the output from typing 'set' at the command prompt?

Comment: @Jeremy I ran 'set' and added to question.

Comment: Your screen shot does not show that you added the correct directory  I suggested to your PATH.

Comment: @Jeremy I updated my files and ran set again and replaced the image in question. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

2 errors:

- You are missing the `bin` folder.
  Usually the correct path is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_version\bin`
- `JAVA_HOME` is usually used by some script or program, if you are interested on running java tools from `cmd` you have to add that directory to `PATH`