# How to change java version in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

I have a simple java project and I try to change java version in Intellij from java 11 to java 8. It isn't a maven project. I found something on google and it looks easy, but it's not working.

So, I pressed ctrl + shift + alt + s and here I changed jdk11 with jdk1.8:

[image]

But now if I run java -version on Intellij terminal I get this in the console:

```
java version "11.0.14" 2022-01-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.14+8-LTS-263)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.14+8-LTS-263, mixed mode)
```

It looks that it continue to use java 11. What else should I do?
Thank you!

Comment: The terminal is just that: a terminal. It will use whatever `java` executable it can find on the `$PATH` / `%PATH%` first. In your case, this seems to be a Java 11 JRE.

Comment: Try to print result of `System.getProperty("java.version")` like `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));` to see what java version is used by IDE to *run* your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the JDK in IntelliJ UI [does not affect](https://www.baeldung.com/intellij-change-java-version#gotchas:%7E:text=this%20only%20affects%20the%20JDK%20used%20by%20IntelliJ) its Intellij terminal:

> When changing the JDK, we need to remember that this only affects the JDK used by IntelliJ. Therefore, **when running the Java project via the command line, it'll still use the JDK specified in the JAVA_HOME environment variable**

So when running `java` on Intellij terminal, you still have to [set `JAVA_HOME`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65661794/11806050) to change java version

Comment: This is only partial correct. It depends on the exact local setup. The `$PATH` / `%PATH%` variable is the determining factor on what JDK is used (although it is best practice to put `$JAVA_HOME/bin` / `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` on the `$PATH` / `%PATH%`).