# Why is Spring changing Java version configs and how to set it properly?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-initializr

I'm using Spring Initializr (https://start.spring.io/) to generate a Spring Boot project.
I've set Java version as 1.8 and hence, Spring Boot version as 2.7.16. Also added Lombok and PostgreSQL dependencies.

When I run my project, however, it displays the following logs:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.16)

2023-10-11 15:07:43.625  INFO 12939 --- [           main] c.j.integrador.IntegradorApplication     : Starting IntegradorApplication using Java 17.0.2 on pc with PID 12939 (/home/<path>/integrador/target/classes started by user in /home/<path>/integrador)
2023-10-11 15:07:43.631  INFO 12939 --- [           main] c.j.integrador.IntegradorApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-10-11 15:07:44.783  INFO 12939 --- [           main] c.j.integrador.IntegradorApplication     : Started IntegradorApplication in 1.908 seconds (JVM running for 3.661)
```

Why is it getting set as Java 17.0.2?

I've already tried changing adding the following lines to POM.xml, although it didn't solve my problem:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

For instance, here's my complete POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.16</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.jotec</groupId>
    <artifactId>integrador</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>integrador</name>
    <description>Integrador de Marketplaces</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Check which version java home is pointing to. Java home should be pointing to the required version

Comment: @subasri_ where is it located?

Comment: you can quickly check version by executing `java --version` in your terminal/cmd. Depending on the OS you use, steps would vary. For eg, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161248/setting-java-home can be referred for windows

Comment: `java -version` outputs to ```openjdk version "1.8.0_362"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_362-8u372-ga~us1-0ubuntu1~18.04-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.362-b09, mixed mode)```. Actually, I've noticed something odd. Eclipses' project config indicates a warning: `When selecting 1.8 compliance, make sure to have a compatible JRE installed and activates (currently 17). Configure 'Installed JREs' and 'Execution Environments', or change the JRE on the 'Java Build Path'.`

Comment: If you're running it from within intellij, etc. you need to set the project SDK. Those properties don't change the run time, just how its compiled. Not sure why you want to use Java 8 though lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it, I had to set the correct JRE to run with my Java application on Eclipse.

Initially, I already had the correct version for Java 1.8 installed on my machine. As I ran the following command, I managed to find the current JRE home path:
`$ java -XshowSettings:properties -version`

```
...
java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
...
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_362-8u372-ga~us1-0ubuntu1~18.04-b09)
...
```

Then I proceeded to access `Window>Preferences>Java>Installed JREs` menu and added a Stantard VM setting the specified path in the JRE home directory (also deleting the previous one I wouldn't use).

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
```

These properties only tell the compiler what version the source and the target (generated code) should be compliant with. I think (but I am not sure) they are only passed to the compiler for the `-source` and `-target` flags.

These properties have nothing to do with the java runtime you use to execute the application. You started the spring boot application with `Java 17.0.2`. But that is not related to the compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure `maven.compiler.source` to java 8, you ask for it to be compiled under Java 8.

In Eclipse:

- Importing a `maven.compiler.source=8` project will tell m2e to use Java-SE-1.8 as *Execution Environments*
- In *Execution Environments*, Eclipse will list all JRE that match the "base level" (here: JavaSE-1.8)
- You need to select a JRE with a perfect match

[image: Execution Environments]

If you don't have such "perfect match" JRE, you need to add one from *Installed JREs* in the preferences then select it in *Execution Environments*