# AVD Manager launch problems

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, virtual-device-manager

My Android Virtual Device Manager is having launch problems. The AVD Manager buttons in Eclipse Juno do not do anything when clicked. I found the `AVD Manager.exe` file in the sdk folder and found that when clicked, a cmd window pops up for 1 second, closes, and then nothing. Anybody know what's wrong with my AVD Manager?

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same problem myself. It seems something must have changed in the AVD between versions.

To solve it I went into `C:\Users\(username)\.android` folder and deleted both the `avd` and `cache` folders. (it may not be necessary to remove both, I didn't check any further)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try to launch SDK-Manager? Is there an open window showing updates, or will this window close after a second too?

### EDIT

Try open "tools" at the top of sdk manager. There you can choose "Manage AVDs". From here it should start, if not then there is  something wrong with the installation of sdk. An other possibility is, that you got a very slow cpu. I got an old acer travelmate, and it lasts two or three minutes to start.
One more thing: the java system variables  have setted wrong. Here is another thread about this problem:

[Android SDK manager won't open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open)

Comment: The sdk manager works perfectly fine, its just the AVD manager that won't open.

Comment: From your suggestions, I determined that something must have gone wrong during installation. I just re-installed and the ADT is working normally now. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Try installing a newer version of JDK. I too had the same problem. I upgraded my JDK from 5 to 7 and AVD manager opened :)