# How to launch AVD manager without launching Android Studio on macOS

Tags: android, macos

While I need to adjust settings in avd manager (I can use emulator @device to launch emulation but if I like to change settings such as camera emulation I need to launch the avd manager), I must first fire up avd manager on macOS. Is there something similar to "AVD manager.exe" on macOS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AVD Manager launch problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534918/avd-manager-launch-problems)