# I can't run the Android SDK Manager through the Eclipse im getting an error in the Console window

Tags: android, eclipse

This is the error/s im getting:

```
[2013-01-21 21:24:14 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] 'lib\find_java.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2013-01-21 21:24:14 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
```

Now I tried to update the Path variable in the computer settings so it looks like:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\bout0_000\android-sdks\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin
```

I just installed now again the `JDK`

And still when clicking on the icon of the Android SDK Manager though the Eclipse im getting this error.

This is the content of the `find_java.bat` file:

```
@echo off
rem Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project
rem
rem Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
rem you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
rem You may obtain a copy of the License at
rem
rem      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
rem
rem Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
rem distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
rem WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
rem See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
rem limitations under the License.

rem This script is called by the other batch files to find a suitable `Java.exe`
rem to use. The script changes the "`java_exe`" env variable. The variable
rem is left unset if Java.exe was not found.

rem Useful links:
rem Command-line reference:
rem   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx

rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path. The return code will
rem be 0 if the command worked or 1 if the exec failed (program not found).
for /f %%a in ('%~dps0\find_java.exe -s') do set java_exe=%%a
if not defined java_exe goto :CheckFailed

:SearchJavaW
rem Check if we can find a javaw.exe at the same location than java.exe.
rem If that doesn't work, just fall back on the java.exe we just found.
for /f %%a in ('%~dps0\find_java.exe -s -w') do set javaw_exe=%%a
if not exist %javaw_exe% set javaw_exe=%java_exe%
goto :EOF


:CheckFailed
echo.
echo ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
echo Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.
echo We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
echo   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads
echo.
echo You can find the complete Android SDK requirements here:
echo   http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html
echo.
goto :EOF
```

This find_java.bat file is located in:

```
C:\Users\my user name\android-sdks\tools\lib
```

What else should I do ? This problem I think was from the beginning when using the Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you told Eclipse where the Android SDK is via:-

Eclipse -> Preferences.

Click the Android section on the left hand side, and set the SDK Location. It should read:-

C:\Users\my user name\android-sdks

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: Actually just noticed it's the SDK Manager you have an issue with, try the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open

Comment: user1998138 your solution is working maybe with the other changes I did before with the path variable but any way now it's working. Thanks.