# My SDK manager did not run.. my OS is windows 8 64 bit

Tags: android

[2013-03-23 02:30:46 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Error: Unable to access jarfile lib\archquery.jar
[2013-03-23 02:30:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Invalid path
[2013-03-23 02:30:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Access is denied.

Comment: You might want to include more information about your problem to get a response.  What exactly happened and what have you tried so far?

Comment: refer...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open/15390396#15390396

Answer (score 0):

set the PATH environment variables.

Right-click myComputer->Properties->Advanced system settings->Environment Variables

Then under System Variables, add a new variable.

Variable    JAVA_PATH
Value       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0

select edit and this %JAVA_PATH%\bin; before