# Sdk Manager won't launch in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

If I choose `Tools` > `Android` > `SDK Manager` from the menu, or click the SDK Manager icon on the tool bar, nothing happens. What can I do to correct the problem?

Comment: you can see this site http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SDK manager won't open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem. When checking the {SDK}/tools/android it said it couldn't create a file, and I noticed it was in a location that needed admin approval.

When launching android studio, launch it as administrator then try it. Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check {SDK}/tools/android launch?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after a failed update 0.3 -> 0.59, I had clean-installed (unzipped) the wrong version (update only, which started just fine, but without SDKs), I had to reinstall the bundle version to even have SDK manager.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#Updating

Answer (score 0):

My sdk manager was working, well, it seems to be working, but as soon as I started to download anything - showed me errors, something like "didnt create directory.." so solution was simple and easy - run as administrator. Or you can just change exe file to run as administrator in properties of this file ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your **Path** environment variable doesn't contain **C:\Windows\System32**. Please try adding it and your error will be resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Launch Android Studio as administrator and disable your anti-virus and try again. My comodo internet security was creating the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu users,change the permission of {SDK}/tools/android to read/write for all users