# SDK manager loads, but closes immediately

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

starting out android programming with Android studio 1.0.1, and got the SDK manager in the bundle downloaded from the website.

When I try to start SDK Manager, it loads until it starts fetching from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, and after that it gets killed.
After trying pretty much every fix I could find on google without success, I decided to resort to asking here.

I have windows 8 64-bit.
I'm using a VPN as I'm currently living in China (incase it affects something).
Android studio and SDK are the latest versions.

EDIT: 
My assumption would be that some other program would kill the loading when it gets that far, but adding exceptions to my firewall and antivirus does not solve this problem.

EDIT2:
After figuring out where the error logs are stored, I managed to conclude this error was caused by outdated JRE. case closed.

Comment: Try this solution:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727109/sdk-manager-wont-launch-in-android-studio

Comment: Yes, I have tried running it as an administrator, doesn't work.
I have also added the path to the environments in the system properties, it is how I got it running that far in the first place.

Comment: From the day you installed Android Studio are you facing this problem? or did you try to modify any thing and then are you getting this error?

Comment: Had it from the beginning. Didn't find it a problem before while I was still learning the basics. Now I need to add other libraries, which forces me to deal with it.

Comment: other libraries means? specific name? will hello world program run now also?

Comment: well, wanted to add new dependencies.
That forces gradle to resync, and it won't do that with other dependencies except the basic one. The fixes to that I've found are solved through the SDK manager, and because SDK manager isn't starting, that's why I'm asking for a solution to it

Comment: Can you please post your dependencies grade file.

Comment: I'd rather see the SDK-manager getting closed before finished loading problem get solved, rather than finding a workaround at this point.

Comment: Sometimes, an antivirus has its own firewall. And you might need to disable it.

Comment: unfortunately that was not the issue either.