# Android debug mode not working waiting for device

Tags: android, fedora

I'm trying to get my android phone working to run apps from inside an IDE.

Got it working on windows no problem,  currently working in fedora (18) a lot though so wanted to get it working with that.

Got IntelliJ and android sdk installed, problem is when I try to run the default hello world app it wont work it just says waiting for device..

Ran adb devices got

```
List of devices attached 

????????????    no permissions
```

Leads me to believe the driver isn't installed? Phone I'm using is a HTC Sensation.  Does anyone know what I can do to try and resolve it?  The HTC web page doesn't offer me drivers to install.

Also noticed in /etc/udev/rules.d/..android.rules there is nothing about Sensation.  Seems it recognises my nexus 7 though..

Edit: Tried my nexus.. got

```
 List of devices     attached 
 901839238298923     offline
```

So it doesn't even work with that.. confusing..

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
B

Comment: have you put Debugging on?

Answer (score 0):

For HTC try downloading HTC sync and give a try..

I also had this problem and i used eclipse IDE. I Re connected and try 2-3 times and after that i run adb devices I got it as online.

Also check out for the devices TAB in eclipse(if you are using that) .It also gives a list of attached devices.

Also try adding this `android:debuggable="true"` to application tag(`<application>`) in androidmanifest.xml

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are installing from the beginning, have you updated the SDK manager.  I have had this issue before too, every time on a new computer it trips me up.  If SDK manager isn't loading see here: [Android SDK manager won't open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open)

Answer (score 0):

I get a similar problem when my user have no permissions, so I did a script to restart the adb on fedora as root:

[Script Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/ademar111190/8527935)

the script basically runs it:

```
su -c ' \
    ADB="/path/to/your/sdk/platform-tools" && \
    $ADB/./adb kill-server && \
    $ADB/./adb start-server \ '
```