# cmd 'where java' produces two results

Tags: java, windows-8, environment-variables

When I do `where java` in the cmd terminal, I get the following results:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
```

Is it meant to do that? I thought it should only produce the first result as that's what's set in my Path environmental variable. I am using Windows 8 if that helps.

Comment: This is the documented behaviour of `where`command on Windows

Comment: So it is meant to do that? I thought java's supposed to be installed in only one place\system's meant to look in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default your `PATH` always have `C:\Windows\System32`, `where` just looks for `the location of the file with search pattern` and in your case, you added `jdk bin` location to your `PATH`, also your `system32` folder also has `java.exe`, thats why you see two entries in your output.

Answer (score 1):

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe` is the entry you get because you defined it in the `Path`.

You are getting the second one, because you have a `java.exe` in your System32 folder. I guess the installer did this.

Comment: Do you think this maybe the cause of why my SDK Manager for Android is not starting? I have looked at posts like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open and android.bat when ran opens SDK manager changing anything. It is just when I click on the actual application that gets the manager not starting..

Comment: Oh never mind I found out why the SDK manager application wasn't starting. It couldnt find the android_home, so I had to set a new environmental variable: `ANDROID_HOME` and point it to my sdk location