# Android SDK Manager will not open

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, cmd

This seems to be a common problem but I've been searching the internet for awhile and I none of the many solutions seem to work.
Here are the errors that are output by either eclipse or running android.bat in a cmd window.

[2014-02-01 19:36:45 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] The system cannot find the file specified.

[2014-02-01 19:36:45 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Error: Error parsing the sdk.

[2014-02-01 19:36:45 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Error: com/google/common/collect/Maps

[2014-02-01 19:36:45 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Error: Unable to parse SDK content.

So how fix?

Answer (score 2):

What Operating System are you running on?

This might help as far as a solution goes, a lot of people say the answers here are helpful: [Android SDK manager won't open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comes across this question looking for an answer:
I re-downloaded the eclipse with adt plugin, sdk, dev tools and whatever else comes with the download on google's developer site. *That* copy of SDKManager.exe worked just fine. 
I just deleted all of the old files, and because I didn't touch the eclipse workspace folder, all of apps-in-progress were just fine.