# Eclipse not working after register clean up

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Today i have cleaned up and fixed my PC after that when i run Eclipse it show a window says :

> An error has occurred. See the log file E:...\configuration\1405452602814.log

and when i open the log file, here is the info :

```
!SESSION 2014-07-15 23:02:07.071 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=v22.0.4-741630
java.version=1.8.0_05
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.126
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.127
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt_0.10.3.v20130124-185622.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.127
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.inject_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.127
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.127
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_2.6.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.127
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_2.6.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.127
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.descriptor_2.6.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.127
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.apache.xerces_2.9.0.v201101211617.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.xerces 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.127
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle javax.xml_[1.3.4,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.128
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/com.sun.el_2.2.0.v201108011116.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.sun.el 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.128
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_2.5.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.129
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.1.v20121109-203239.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.129
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_[2.6.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.129
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_[2.6.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.129
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui_2.2.0.v20130119-010614.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.129
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.129
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk_1.0.200.v20120515-1650.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.129
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.129
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler_1.1.0.v20110815-1744.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.129
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.129
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.10.3.v20130124-133900.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.129
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.batik.css.engine_1.6.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.129
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.129
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.inject_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.129
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.w3c.css.sac_1.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.129
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.10.3.v20130123-162658.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.130
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.131
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.w3c.css.sac_1.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.131
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/javax.el_2.2.0.v201108011116.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 javax.el 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.131
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_2.5.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 javax.el 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.131
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_2.5.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.132
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.1.300.v20120912-130548.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.132
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.132
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_[2.3.0,3.1.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.132
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_[2.3.0,3.1.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.132
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jsch.core_1.1.400.v20120522-1148.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jsch.core 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.133
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.jcraft.jsch_[0.1.28,1.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.133
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.10.2.v20120912-132817.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.133
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.batik.css_[1.6.0,1.7.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.133
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.w3c.css.sac_1.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.133
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.133
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry_1.0.300.v20120912-130548.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.134
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_2.4.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.134
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.134
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_2.4.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.134
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings_0.10.3.v20130123-162658.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.134
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.inject_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.134
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.http_8.1.3.v20120522.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.http 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.134
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_2.6.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.http 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.134
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_2.6.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.135
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions_0.11.100.v20121024-182359.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.135
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.inject_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.135
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.net_1.2.101.v20120914-093638.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.net 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.135
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.135
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.core.commands_0.10.1.v20120523-1955.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.core.commands 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.135
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.inject_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.135
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jsch.ui_1.1.400.v20120522-1148.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jsch.ui 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.135
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.jcraft.jsch_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.135
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.egit.ui_2.2.0.201212191850-r.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.135
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.jcraft.jsch_[0.1.37,0.2.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.135
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.9.4.v20130123-162658.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.135
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.w3c.css.sac_1.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.135
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.135
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.v20130116-182509.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.help.webapp 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.135
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_2.4.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.help.webapp 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.135
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet_2.4.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.135
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jgit_2.2.0.201212191850-r.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jgit 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.135
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.jcraft.jsch_[0.1.37,0.2.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.135
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.136
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.136
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui_3.104.0.v20121024-145224.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.136
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.136
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.services_0.10.3.v20130123-162658.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.services 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.136
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.inject_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.services 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.136
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.136
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.104.0.v20130204-164612.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.136
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.inject_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.136
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom.css_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.136
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed_3.5.300.v20120912-132807.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.136
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.136
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.server 2 0 2014-07-15 23:02:09.136
!MESSAGE Missing imported package javax.servlet.http_2.6.0.
```

This is not all the file, Because it's too large to post it here!

I tried the install a fresh eclipse and it's works but when i import my old projects i have an error :

> The import android.support.v7.app cannot be resolved

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup the supporting libraries?

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: The SDK Manager in not working !
When i launch it nothing opens!

Comment: Try looking at the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open

Comment: Noting works !

when i run android.bat i have this errors :

The system cannot find the file specified, Error parsing the sdk, Error com/google/commo/collect/Multimap and Error Unable to parse SDK content !