# Unable to create new android virtual device manager (AVD)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have downloaded latest ANDROID SDK on October 9, 2014 from

https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i

```
Eclipse + ADT plugin
Android SDK Tools
Android Platform-tools
A version of the Android platform
A version of the Android system image for the emulator
```

I am using Corei7 laptop, having more than sufficient requirements.

when i ran Eclipse from ADT BUNDL and wanted to create new AVD manager, I filled all required text boxes and selected dropdown boxes in Create new avd manager window 
As shown below:
[image]

But OK button is disabled. (Note that Android SDK Manager window is not opening)

Comment: just reduce the size for sdcard

Comment: @MeenalSharma Dear; I tried that too, but still same problem; I think it matters due to latest API Level 20,  what do u say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frieds, I have finally found solution; Every thing was fine, I suddenly ran eclipse as administrator and every worked fine.
thanks you all.

Answer (score 3):

This is because no CPU/ABI was selected for this emulator.
In you case you have to install it from the Android-SDK manager:
Under each android version you can install both ARM EABI system image and Intel system image.
Install one of them and then try to recreate the emulator.

Update:
Install the relevant system image according to API level.
If you are trying to start API level 20 emulator, verify the system image is also install under  this API level.

Comment: Android SDK manager is not opening

Comment: see my update - install the relevant system image for your emulator @RajaRassani

Answer (score 1):

Firstly go to [SDK manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html) plugin of Your eclipse and choose the API level for which you are going to create Android Virtual Device. And make sure that API's SDK Platform is installed. If SDK showing Not installed , then firstly download it.

After automatic Installation on Downloading completion. Restart your eclipse. Start your AVD plugin and then select the API for your AVD that you download.

Check this image, it showing that SDK platform for API 17 is installed. So we can create AVD of API 17. BUT we cant create AVD of API 16, because it is not installed yet.

[image]

Comment: Sir, sdk manager window was not opening

Comment: what it's saying? @RajaRassani

Comment: Sir, See my own answer at bottom... I am nothing instead of all senior members who are helping me here, I am very thankful to you all for.

Comment: are you able to see SDK Manager icon in eclipse? what happening when you click on SDK Manager icon?

Comment: @RajaRassani You may refere this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open

Comment: Thanks sir @shylendra, it was just a problem regarding permissions by windows operating system who was blocking all requests if its not by administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
Android Virtual Device:
AVD Name: AVD_for_2_7in_QVGA
Device: 2.7"QVGA(240x320:ldpi)
Target :Android 4.3-API Level 18
RAM:512
VM Heap:16
Internal Storage: 200MB
```