# Daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 * Cannot open 'nul': The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, android

Eclipse gives following error while running android program...

**Error 1:**

```
[2015-12-10 16:10:37 - adb] Cannot open 'nul': The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
[2015-12-10 16:10:37 - ddms] 'D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
[2015-12-10 16:10:37 - adb] * failed to start daemon *
[2015-12-10 16:10:37 - adb] error: cannot connect to daemon
```

And when I start from command line I get this error...

**Error 2:**

```
D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
Cannot open 'nul': The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

Previously even `AVD Manager.exe` and `SDK manager.exe` was not opening  when I double click on it. After doing Rnd on google I found this post    [Android SDK manager won't open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open#) and I made changes to android.bat as follow :

I replace this

```
rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
set java_exe=
call lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
```

with this code

```
set java_exe=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe
```

Now when I double click on `AVD Manager.exe` and `SDK manager.exe` it opens well.

I also checked with new eclipse (Mars) and added ADT plug in and created Hello World Application and tried to run but its gives same **Error 1**

Update 2:

I get below error..

```
D:\>set ADB_TRACE=adb

D:\>adb start-server
adb I  6072  2636 adb.cpp:219] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
adb I  6072  2636 adb.cpp:219] Revision 09a0d98bebce-android
adb I  6072  2636 adb.cpp:219]
adb I  6072  2636 adb_client.cpp:126] _adb_connect: host:version
adb I  6072  2636 sysdeps_win32.cpp:742] could not connect to tcp:5037: cannot c
onnect to 127.0.0.1:5037: No connection could be made because the target machine
 actively refused it. (10061)
adb I  6072  2636 adb_client.cpp:175] adb_connect: service host:start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
Cannot open 'nul': The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

I checked whether port 5037 is used by other program but it is not showing

```
netstat -aon|findstr 5037
```

What is error exactly..system refused connection on port 5037 what does it mean  how to resolve it. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty late answer, I doubt you nearly forgot about it, but it would help other people facing this issue.
Since you got this error :

```
Cannot open 'nul': The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

The problem is in the `ADB.exe` executable it self which may be corrupted or having permission or ownership issue.

If it is just a permission problem  you can check it by copying (from *"D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\"*) :

```
ADB.exe
AdbWinApi.dll
AdbWinUsbApi.dll
```

past it in a new folder in your desktop and run `adb.exe devices` in that directory *(hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right click anywhere in the directory not in files and open command window here*).
if you see this you are good:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

if it failed again ,then it is corrupted and you have to replace the whole 3 files
download them from here [adbshell.com](http://adbshell.com/downloads)