# Android Studio sdk manager is not opening

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-manager

My Android sdk manager isn't opening it shows Like it is about to open like the picture but won't open.I searched some solutions on the internet and stackoverflow that said to edit in the android.bat file by changing the swt_path to lib\x86 or change the set java_exe to the path of java.exe in jre7 bin folder but none of the solutions worked for me. I'm unable to figure out what is wrong with this.It was working fine a few months ago.Please help
[sdk manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvWd6.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SDK manager won't open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open)

Comment: Even this didn't work