# Android studio keeps saying: Error:Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25' in: C:\Users\Jogo\AppDat

Tags: android

I don't know what is happening for the past 2 weeks I have been trying to make android studio work and this error keeps popping up and things are not working.
Screenshot:

[image: Error message]

And then when I try to update sdk platform-tools this it says it doing something but it just sits there.

[image: saying its downloading]

Someone please help im going crazy trying to fix this.

Comment: normally it takes some time to install sdk components using android studio - depending on available resources of the pc at that time. how long have you waited for the installation process to complete?

Comment: I waited 4 hours for it to complete

Comment: have you tried installing this same component using the standalone sdk manager - not using android studio?

Comment: do a: "adb kill-server" on a command line, then try to update again.

Comment: Do you mean cmd?

Comment: I haven't tried to install it through the sdk manager. Where do you find it. Im kinda new to this

Comment: do you know where you installed android sdk? if you know, go to that location - inside that location find and open `SDK Manager.exe`.

Comment: I went to the android developer website and it says that in android studio 25.2 and higher does not have the standalone instead something else link: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html

Comment: @Jogozin yes. run "adb kill-server" on a cmd then try to install api 25 and platform tools again.

Comment: when i tried "adb kill-server" it says * server not running *

Comment: @Jogozin go to `C:\Users\Jogo\Appdata\Local\Android\Sdk` - inside that folder, run `SDK Manager.exe`

Comment: http://imgur.com/3Ag8pg3

Comment: then go to `tools` folder inside that location - then run `android.bat` inside that folder.

Comment: When I run android.bat it flashes and exits.

Comment: looks like you have a problem with your android sdk. if it was working properly, you would see something like [this](http://imgur.com/a/X2SsP).

Comment: I kinda see the same thing but in android studio http://imgur.com/F76VTiJ http://imgur.com/3Ag8pg3

Comment: there is a slight difference in functionality between what i've shown and what you see. anyways, you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43247051/5456631) so that you can see what i've shown. (before doing that, close android studio) then my instructions should work.

Comment: after doing that, do not update android sdk tools using android studio - then this problem with android sdk will be back again.

Comment: None of those methods worked. Im probably just going to reset my computer.. nothing's working