# Launch Standalone SDK Manager doesn't works

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

when I click on "launch standalone SDK Manager", I am using the android studio 2.1.3 it doesn't respond. I have installed JDK and set the Environment Path too.
I am new in android.Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SDK manager won't open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open)

Comment: @Tauqir My SDK Manager open and can update too, but "Launch Standalone SDK Manager" link does not work when I click on it, and I can't see the extras folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standalone SDK manager doesn't exists in Android Studio 2.3.1

Comment: I am using Android Studio 2.1.3, Launch Standalone SDK Manager show in SDK manager but not respond to click

Comment: Upgrade Android studio always use lates edition. So you will use internally(inside android studio ) SDK Manager.