# Android - AVD Manager and SDK Manager not loading

Tags: android, android-studio

I can no longer seem to open the `AVD Manager.exe` or `SDK Manager.exe` on my Windows machine. When I open these programs, a console window very briefly appears, which then disappears, and nothing else seems to be open.

I have installed Android SDK from the Andriod Studio. The Android SDK is located in `C:\Users\yahya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`.

Note that I can seem to interact with just fine using the Andriod Studio itself. But I want to also be able to open the standalone `AVD Manager.exe` and `SDK Manager.exe` programs.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43246607/5456631) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43247051/5456631)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standalone GUIs previously in the Android SDK for AVD & SDK management were deprecated: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html

The replacement are command line tools or the GUI tools inside of Android Studio:

- SDKManager - https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html
- AVD Manager - https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager.html