# How to open Android SDK manager from terminal?

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I have installed Android Studio and SDK Tools. Now the issue is when i tried to open sdkmanager from terminal it does not open anything. It says completing updates 100% but does not open anything and stuck. below is the output in terminal:

> ARSLAANs-MBP:bin arslaan$ sdkmanager
>   [=======================================] 100% Computing updates...

Note: SDK tools directory and JAVA_HOME is added as environment variables

Please help and thanks

Comment: not so, my sdkmanager command is working without any error but not showing anything.

Comment: I don't agree this is a duplicate of the referred older question. I have this issue in 2018 and the older questions was answered 2014. A lot has changed since then.

Comment: The current answer to this question is that the all the visual tools that you previously ran from the command line are now part of android studio, which is free. The command line tools still work, try .sdkmanager --list for example, but they output to the terminal.

Comment: As john said, this is not a duplicate. i asked that command is running but not showing anything which is a totally different question from which you marked as duplicate.

Comment: This is not a duplicate IMO. I still cannot fix it

Comment: This is not a duplicate - the linked question does not have an adequate answer to this question as of 2019, and is also bloated with outdated answers.

Comment: It is a duplicate. If a lot has changed, then edit the target duplicate answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open to include a solution for how thing have changed. That's what collaborative wiki Q&As are for.